# How to import a class and tap into its __init__ attributes without initialising it in python?

Tags: python, initialization, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am trying to add some futures to my snake game. What I want to do is every third point that the snake eats, there is a mega point and its value is 3 instead of 1.

```
from turtle import Turtle
import random


class Food(Turtle):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.shape("square")
        self.penup()
        self.shapesize(stretch_len=0.5, stretch_wid=0.5)
        self.color("#C9C9C9")
        self.speed(10)
        self.refresh()

    def refresh(self):
        random_x = random.randint(-280, 280)
        random_y = random.randint(-280, 265)
        self.goto(random_x, random_y)
```

```
from turtle import Turtle
ALIGNMENT = 'center'
FONT = ('Courier', 22, 'normal')


class Scoreboard(Turtle):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.score = 0
        with open('data.txt') as data:  # open and reading a file
            self.high_score = int(data.read())
        self.color('white')
        self.penup()
        self.goto(x=0, y=270)
        self.hideturtle()
        self.update_scoreboard()

    def update_scoreboard(self):
        self.clear()
        self.write(f"Score: {self.score} High score: {self.high_score}", align=ALIGNMENT, font=FONT)

    def reset(self):
        if self.score > self.high_score:
            self.high_score = self.score
            with open('data.txt', mode='w') as data:  # writing to a file
                data.write(f"{self.high_score}")
        self.score = 0
        self.update_scoreboard()

    def increase_score(self):
        if self.score % 5 == 0:
            self.score += 3
        else:
            self.score += 1
        self.update_scoreboard()
```

What I thought is to use the modulo% in the scoreboard.py to increase the score attribute by 3 points every third food spawn, and I have managed to do that, the problem is, I do not know how to either tap into the scoreboard score attribute and change the color of the food in relation to the score without having two overlayed scoreboards on screen, or create some kind of loop in food.py that achieves the same functionality by looping through a list of colors.

I've also tried this method answered by another person on here but I couldn't make it work.

```
import inspect

params = []
for parent in ExampleParams.mro()[::-1]:
    parent_init = inspect.getfullargspec(parent.__init__)
    # parent_init.annotations contains annotations if specified in method signature
    for param in parent_init.args:
        if param == 'self':
            continue
        params.append(param)
```

Comment: When/where does `increase_score` get called. Probably what you should do is have the method take the number of points to increase as an argument, and whoever *calls* `increase_score` is responsible for determining if the score should increase by 1 or 3.

Comment: `increase_score` is called in `main.py` when the snake head is close to the food. I apologise if I wasn't explicit enough, the scoring of point works just fine now, all I want to do is change the food color every time the score increases by 3.

Comment: The point is, `increase_score` shouldn't have anything to do with that. Both the color and the point total would be attributes of an instance of `Food`, and whatever is responsible for handling that bit of food being eaten can capture its value and pass it on so that it reaches the call to `increase_score`.

Comment: (Or at least, the time at which `Food` is instantiated is the time to determine its point value and it color *for* the instance, rather than the instance itself choosing its color and value.)

Comment: This is missing a [mcve] showing the calling code. Using metaprogramming like `inspect.getfullargspec(parent.__init__)` isn't necessary. If the Scoreboard provides a getter to access the score and the Food has parameters to change its color behavior, the code that instantiates both of these classes can connect the two appropriately and implement the desired functionality.